# How to execute a query with argument substitution from a row in another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, for-loop, foreach, subquery

I need to generate a metric value for each combination of parameters from a table.

I have one table from which I take data.
An example would be the following:

| meas_count | skippings | links | ovf_part | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 4.2 | 0.5 | some |
| 10 | 9 | 5.8 | 0.25 | some |
| 10 | 9 | 5.8 | 0.25 | some_2 |
| 11 | 8 | 4.2 | 0.5 | some |
| 11 | 8 | 5.8 | 0.75 | some |
| 11 | 9 | 5.9 | 0.25 | some |

To calculate the metrics, this table is transformed into another view by the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT meas_count,skippings
    FROM current_stats
    GROUP BY meas_count,skippings
) AS one
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LAG(rounded) OVER (ORDER BY rounded) as links_min, 
    rounded as links_max FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROUND(links, 1) as rounded FROM current_stats) 
        GROUP BY rounded
    ORDER BY rounded  
    )
) AS two;
```

This results is the following table (*intermed-table*):

| meas_count | skippings | links_min | links_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | NULL | 4 |
| 10 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 10 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 10 | 9 | NULL | 4 |
| 10 | 9 | 4 | 5 |
| 10 | 9 | 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 8 | NULL | 4 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 11 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 11 | 9 | NULL | 4 |
| 11 | 9 | 4 | 5 |
| 11 | 9 | 5 | 6 |

For each row of the resulting table, I need to apply a query to the main table to calculate the metric. The query is the following:

```sql
SELECT SUM(cnt) as metric FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(ovf_part) as cnt FROM current_stats 
    WHERE meas_count = @meas_count AND skippings = @skippings AND links >= @links_min AND links < @links_max 
    GROUP BY ROUND(ovf_part, 3)
)
```

The query specified earlier must be applied to each row of *intermed-table*. The `@` sign denotes fields whose value must be taken from the row of the *intermed-table*.

As a result, I would like to get a table like this:

| meas_count | skippings | links_min | links_max | metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | NULL | 4 | metric-value1 |
| 10 | 8 | 4 | 5 | metric-value2 |
| 10 | 8 | 5 | 6 | metric-value3 |
| 10 | 9 | NULL | 4 | metric-value4 |
| 10 | 9 | 4 | 5 | metric-value5 |
| 10 | 9 | 5 | 6 | metric-value6 |
| 11 | 8 | NULL | 4 | metric-value7 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 | 5 | metric-value8 |
| 11 | 8 | 5 | 6 | metric-value9 |
| 11 | 9 | NULL | 4 | metric-value10 |
| 11 | 9 | 4 | 5 | metric-value11 |
| 11 | 9 | 5 | 6 | metric-value12 |

I would like all the processing to be done in one request, i.e. without the need to create intermediate representations (views).

**It is possible to implement the calculation of the metrics for each row in one query (not in script)?**

**If yes, how to implement such *for each* and make representation in the table with indicated earlier structure?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
It can be done using the following query:

```sql
SELECT *, (
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(ovf_part) as cnt FROM current_stats 
    WHERE meas_count = meas_count_ref AND skippings = skippings_ref AND links >= links_min AND links < links_max 
    GROUP BY ROUND(ovf_part, 3)
    )
) as metric
FROM 
(
    SELECT meas_count as meas_count_ref, skippings as skippings_ref
    FROM current_stats
    GROUP BY meas_count,skippings
) AS one
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LAG(rounded) OVER (ORDER BY rounded) as links_min, 
    rounded as links_max FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROUND(links, 1) as rounded FROM current_stats) 
        GROUP BY rounded
    ORDER BY rounded  
    )
) AS two;
```

The only difference is that the names of the first two columns of the resulting table will be slightly different, due to the introduction of aliases with a non-conflicting names. You can keep the old names if you use alias for the intermediate table. It can be done like this:

```sql
SELECT *, (
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(ovf_part) as cnt FROM current_stats 
    WHERE meas_count = intermediate.meas_count AND skippings = intermediate.skippings AND links >= links_min AND links < links_max 
    GROUP BY ROUND(ovf_part, 3)
    )
) as metric
FROM (
(
    SELECT meas_count, skippings
    FROM current_stats
    GROUP BY meas_count,skippings
) AS one
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LAG(rounded) OVER (ORDER BY rounded) as links_min, 
    rounded as links_max FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROUND(links, 1) as rounded FROM current_stats) 
        GROUP BY rounded
    ORDER BY rounded  
    )
) AS two
) AS intermediate;
```